# How to find the file name in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a Question. I'm a little bit confuse in it. I have URL from which images and videos are coming.I want to get the name from that link and check it is it an image or video and perform action on it. like

```
if filename.endwith(.jpg or .png):
   print("it's an image")
else filename.endwith(.mp4, .avi):
   print("it's a video)
```

the filename is a list. in which all the data are store:

```
        ls = ["C:/Users/OB/Desktop/DevoMech Project/6.JPG" , "C:/Users/OB/Desktop/DevoMech Project/7.JPG"]

    if ls.endwith(.JPG or .JPEG):

        item1 = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(QIcon(ls), "item1")
        self.dlistWidget.addItem(item1)
        #item2 = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(QIcon("C:/Users/OB/Desktop/DevoMech Project/7.JPEG"), "item2")
        self.dlistWidget.addItem(item2)
```

and instead of item one the actual name display.

Comment: Can you share a couple of links ?

Comment: this code does not even compile. You have various syntax issues

Comment: what is `filename` type?

Comment: Please provide an error message and example input filename

Comment: hi bro, i want to store all the images name in list. filename is a list of images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from urlparse import urlparse
from os.path import splitext

url = "sample/test/image.png"


image_formats = [".png", ".jpeg"]
video_formats = [".mp4", ".mp3", ".avi"]

def get_ext(url):
    """Return the filename extension from url, or ''."""
    parsed = urlparse(url)
    root, ext = splitext(parsed.path)
    return ext  


if get_ext(url) in image_formats:
   print("it's an image")
elif get_ext(url) in video_formats:
    print("it's a video")
else:
    print("some differnet format")
```

it will work for any type of url

```
www.example.com/image.jpg
https://www.example.com/page.html?foo=1&bar=2#fragment
https://www.example.com/resource
```

Comment: Bro an error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/OB/Desktop/DevoMech Project/url_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from urlparse import urlparse
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urlparse'

Comment: For Python 3, use: from urllib.parse import urlparse

Answer (score 2):

I always prefer to use the os builtin if possible for paths and also capture unsupported types

```py
import os
video_types = ('.mp4', '.avi', '.jpeg')
image_types = ('.png', '.jpg')
filenames = ["/test/1.jpg","/test/2.avi","/test/unknown.xml","/test/noextention"]

for filename in filenames:
    print(filename)
    if os.path.splitext(filename)[1] in video_types:
        print("Its a Video")
    elif os.path.splitext(filename)[1] in image_types:
        print("Its an Image")
    else:
        print("No Idea")
```

```
/test/1.jpg

Its an Image

/test/2.avi

Its a Video

/test/unknown.xml

No Idea

/test/noextention

No Idea
```

Comment: bro gave an error
    if os.path.splittext(ls)[1] in video_types:
AttributeError: module 'ntpath' has no attribute 'splittext'

Comment: It's `splitext`, not `splittext`. Single t. For "split extension"

Comment: one more thing that instead of image like Print(it's an image") the image name displayed. like print('it's image of" + image_name)

Answer (score 0):

```py
if filename.lower().endswith(('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg')):
   print("it's an image")
elif filename.lower().endswith(('.mp4', '.avi')):
   print("it's a video")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use String inbuilt split method.
For ex:-

```
file_name = 'my_image.jpg'
file_type = file_name.split('.')[-1] # it will give you 'jpg' last element
```

Comment: For your example input this works, but if the file has no extension youll return the files name. Youd want file_type to be empty.